# what is the state of class field theory for fields that aren't $\mathbb{Q}$, imaginary quadratic, or a function field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am aware that the theory of complex multiplication provides us with special functions whose values describe $K^\text{ab}$ where $K$ is an imaginary quadratic extension of the rationals.  And that drinfeld modules provide a similarly explicit description of the maximal abelian extension of a global function field.

I am [vaguely] aware that the langlands programme would give us information about nonabelian extensions of global fields.

But what the problem of giving a concrete set of generators for abelian extensions of other fields $K$ when $K$ is not $\mathbb{Q}$, an imaginary quadratic number field, or a global function field?  Why can't CM work on say, a real abelian number field?  What goes wrong when you try to take the ideas of drinfeld modules back to an arbitrary number field?

Put another way - what is the state of Hilbert's 12th problem?  Is it entirely subsumed by the langlands programme? And if not, what are the other proposed lines of attack?

Comment: About [this Drinfeld module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinfeld_module), what I know is that thanks to the Riemann-Roch theorem, finite extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ are much easier than finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ when studying their zeta functions (the Langland program), see this [proof of the RH](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~ratazzi/nivedita.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

As one out of many attempts at constructing class fields let me point out the work by Henri Darmon (see e.g. 
[Elliptic Curves and Class Fields of Real Quadratic Fields: Algorithms and Evidence](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1057860313)) on the construction of class fields of real quadratic number fields.